# add an if echo statement to my search engine

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a search engine and because of the paralympics, I want people to be able to see a h1 countdown I have placed at the top of my site.  Underneath will be the looped results from my database.  Any ideas where I go wrong? because in this `if`, it won't echo the `h1` tag at all.  I would like to above my results.

```
$query = " SELECT * FROM scan WHERE "; 

$terms = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $terms);
$i     = 0;
foreach ($terms as $each) {
    if ($i++ !== 0) {
        $query .= " OR ";
    }
    $query .= "keywords LIKE '%{$each}%'";
}
// Don't append the ORDER BY until after the loop
$query .= "ORDER BY rank";

$query   = mysql_query($query) or die('MySQL Query Error: ' . mysql_error($connect));
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows > 0) {

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $id          = $row['id'];
        $title       = $row['title'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $keywords    = $row['keywords'];
        $link        = $row['link'];
        $rank        = $row['rank'];

        echo '<h2><a class="ok" href="' . $link . '">' . $title . '</a></h2>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<p maxlength="10" class="kk">' . $description . '</p>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<p><a class="okay" href="' . $link . '">' . $link . '<br><br><span class="keywords"></p>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
} else {
    echo "No results found for \"<b>{$k}</b>\"";
}


if ($k = "Paralympics 2012") {
    echo "<h1> Countdown to Paralympics: 7 Days </h1>";
}
```

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: and $k is never initialized, at least not in the code shown

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($k = "Paralympics 2012") {
    echo "<h1> Countdown to Paralympics: 7 Days </h1>";
}
```

Will always print the `<h1>`. You're doing assignment rather than comparison. Try:

```
if ($k == "Paralympics 2012")
```

Also, verify that $k is what you expect it to be when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

One equals (`=`) *assigns*, and two/three (`==`/`===`) *compares*.  The line

```
if ($k = "Paralympics 2012") {
```

Assigns `$k` to a string, which always returns true, because any string other than an empty one (`""`) is truthy.  Try this:

```
if ($k === "Paralympics 2012") {
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, the `<h1>` is *always* displaying, opposite of what you're question states. It's always displaying due to the fact that you're doing an assignment of a non-false value with:

```
if ($k = "Paralympics 2012") {
```

Update that to use a comparison to fix that logic issue.

```
if ($k == "Paralympics 2012") {
```

Next, to get it to display above your results, you need to actually move that `if-statement` above the loop that `echo`s the results. Try placing it in the `if ($numrows > 0) {` block, like this:

```
if ($numrows > 0) {
    if ($k == "Paralympics 2012") {
        echo "<h1> Countdown to Paralympics: 7 Days </h1>";
    }
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        ...
```